# Linker prefers weak symbol?

Tags: c, linux, linker

I can't get the linker to prefer a symbol in a dynamic library instead of using a local weak symbol in one of the object files. I use here lld, but the same happens with the GNU ld:

```
# tail -n10 {a,main}.c
==> a.c <==
#include <stdlib.h>

__attribute__((weak))
int puts(const char *ignore) {
    abort();
}


==> main.c <==
int puts(const char*);

int main() {
    puts("Should work");
}

# clang-16 -c {a,main}.c
# readelf -r main.o

Relocation section '.rela.text' at offset 0x180 contains 2 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000000007  000300000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .L.str - 4
00000000000c  000500000004 R_X86_64_PLT32    0000000000000000 puts - 4

Relocation section '.rela.eh_frame' at offset 0x1b0 contains 1 entry:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000000020  000200000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .text + 0
# readelf --syms a.o   

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 5 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS a.c
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 .text
     3: 0000000000000000    17 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT    2 puts
     4: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND abort
# clang-16 -fuse-ld=lld -v -Wl,--trace-symbol=puts /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 {a,main}.o
Debian clang version 16.0.6 (++20230710041738+7cbf1a259152-1~exp1~20230710161755.7)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/lib/llvm-16/bin/ld.lld" -pie --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o a.out /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/lib -L/usr/lib --trace-symbol=puts /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 a.o main.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtendS.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: shared definition of puts
a.o: definition of puts
main.o: reference to puts
# ./a.out 
Aborted (core dumped)
# gdb -quiet a.out
Reading symbols from a.out...
(No debugging symbols found in a.out)
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000001780 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000001781 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000001784 <+4>: lea    -0x11df(%rip),%rdi        # 0x5ac
   0x000000000000178b <+11>:    call   0x1760 <puts>
   0x0000000000001790 <+16>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000001792 <+18>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000001793 <+19>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
```

The relocation is resolved by hardcoding the local `puts` instead of it going through the PLT. I'm not creating a static executable...

Answer (score 2):

`ld` does not take a symbol from a library if it already has a definition for it, even a weak definition. Change the link command to list the library before the module that contains the weak symbol. (But the library must remain after any modules that use symbols from it. If the module that contains the weak symbol needs other things from the library, split it into two modules.)

Comment: Not sure if I understood, but if I change the order like this: `clang-16 -fuse-ld=lld -v -Wl,--trace-symbol=puts /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 {main,a}.o`, the output of trace-symbol changes: `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: shared definition of puts
main.o: reference to puts
a.o: definition of puts`, but the binary looks the same (aborts)

Comment: See the sentence “But the library must remain after any modules that use symbols from it.” in the answer.

Comment: OK here is my interpretation of your words. The only library here is libc. The object file using it is main.o. So if the library must be after any modules that use symbols from it, the order would be "a.o main.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6". That doesn't work. Neither does "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 main.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 a.o", for that matter. It seems no matter the position of a.o in the command line, the moment it's introduced it overrides the symbol in the shared lib

Comment: The library must be after `main.o` and `a.o` must be after the library. That means `main.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 a.o`. In addition, since `a.o` needs `abort`, instead of splitting in into two modules as this answer suggests, you could try listing the library a second time `main.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 a.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`. “That doesn't work” is not an adequate problem description, and no diagnosis can be made from it.